# How to add and remove tag based on the value of a custom field using civirules

Tags: civirules, tags

I have a YES/No radio Custom field for individual.

When the custom field is set to Yes, I would like to tag the contact. And when NO is selected, I would like to remove the tag.

I have managed to update tag to YES by following rule:

Linked Trigger: Custom Data on Contact (of any Type) Changed

Linked Condition(s):Field Value Comparison  Contact.custom_273 = 1 (basically saying when YES is selected)

Linked Action(s): Add Tag to a Contact

But when I use the similar pattern of rules with "Contact.custom_273 = 0" I never managed to get this working. Did anyone managed to get similar rule to wok? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Old post, but I've got the same question, so I'm wondering if you ever found a solution. I've got a custom field that I'd like to have updated automatically when anything on the contact record is changed. It looks like the rule is triggering correctly, but the custom field never gets updated.